# Nightly Script that Inserts values into different sheet based on date - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet "Sheet1" where a user inputs data in cells A3:E3. The goal is to then move that data into "Sheet2" where column A4:A34 is a numeric value for the day of the month. I want to move the data inputted on "Sheet1" into "Sheet2" on the row that corresponds with the current day of the month. Then "Sheet1" would clear itself for the next day ahead.

[image]

I'll be honest I'm not great with functions and I'm mainly looking for help on where to look to find a solution. I've tried different code that I do know how to use like Query but the issue is it doesn't lock the value in place and as soon as the values are wiped in Sheet1 they are then removed via the query.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Is there a specific step where you are getting stuck? Can you show us what you have tried? It's often easier to help if you can [edit] the question and share the relevant details. As it stands, this question is currently too broad.

Comment: Otherwise, welcome! - and don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @andrewjames It's more so how I can get the data to stick. So I believe it will need to be a function. I can go to sheet2 and query the data from sheet 1 based on the date. The issue is as soon as the information clears from Sheet1 so does the results from the query.

Comment: I can't use a google form because the data isn't finalized until the end of day. So "Sheet1" is a running log for that day. Once the day is over and the numbers are finalized the data needs to be moved to Sheet2 based on the day of the month.

Comment: Understood - you should [edit] your question and provide your clarifications there, not in a comment. However, SO is not a code writing service. Someone may just do that for you, but you may also find your question gets closed/downvoted due to a lack of demonstrated research/effort (just to warn you).

Comment: @andrewjames I understand that. I am more so looking for someone to point me in the right direction. Using google to look up terms like "Write values from one sheet to another based on value" or "Move data from one sheet to another nightly" returns too many results that don't apply to my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run a function on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). The function can use `Range.getValues()` to read the data, get the current date's day number with `const dayNumber = new Date().getDate()`, look up the day number in Sheet2 with `Range.getValues().flat().indexOf(dayNumber)`, write the data with `Range.setValues()` and finally clear the source range with `Range.clearContent()`.

It is unclear what the purpose the day numbers in Sheet2 serve, because the data would in any case be written once a day. It would seem simpler to always append the most recent data at the first available row and include a timestamp.

For an example of how to do this, see the [appendRowsToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/41717054?msgid=43025271) script.

Answer (score 0):

Since the task is rather simple, here is the code that does the work:

```
// add menu Scripts

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Scripts')
  .addItem('✅ Copy to archive', 'copy_range_to_archive')
  .addItem('❌ Erase', 'erase_range')
  .addToUi();
}


// erase the range A3:E3

function erase_range() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheets()[0]
  .getRange("A3:E3")
  .clearContent();
}


// copy the range A3:E3 to Sheet 2

function copy_range_to_archive() {
  const ss         = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const src_range  = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A3:E3");
  const data       = src_range.getValues();
  const dest_sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  const today      = new Date().getDate();
  const dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange(3 + today, 2, 1, data[0].length);
  
  dest_range.clearContent();
  dest_range.setValues(data);
}
```

It makes the menu 'Scripts' and two command 'Copy to archive' (the range A3:E3) and 'Erase' (the same range).

[image]